# Tab jquery auto scroll with click

Tags: jquery, tabs, autoscroll

I'm been looking jquery auto scroll on tab, then i found

http://codepen.io/yanxurui/pen/rVovyN

But i want the tab change on click, not hover. Then i try change this

```
function currentHover() {
  $(".tabAuto li").hover(function() {
  }
```

to

```
function currentHover() {
  $(".tabAuto li").click(function() {
  }
```

but the auto scroll start jumping around the tab.
I like to know if there is any good approach to click on tab

Comment: your project is not bootstrap?, or you can use, `https://jqueryui.com/tabs/` jquery ui tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to change the `.hover` to `.click` in the `contentHover` function:

```
function contentHover() {
  // in this function change hover to click.
}
```